# TSQL Question About Update Column with Hierarchy in Value

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, hierarchical-data

I have this table with two columns, Hierarchy (Alphabet order) and Access as below.

```
N  Hierarchy                    Access
1  A                            Y
2  A >B                         N
3  A >B >C                      NULL
4  A >B >C >D                   NULL
5  A >B >C >D >E                NULL
6  A >B >C >D >E >F             NULL
7  A >B >C >D >E >F >G          Y
8  A >B >C >D >E >F >G >J       NULL
```

I need to update Access column with this logic. If the Access value is null, update the Access for this row with Access from next higher hierarchy where Access is not null.

For example,

Row 7's Access is null, the query will update Row 7's Access to Y. Because hierarchy                       G is Y.

Row 6 will be N, because hierarchy E, D and C is null, and B is N (not null).

Row 5 will be N, because hierarchy D and C is null, and B is N (not null).

Row 4 will be N, because hierarchy C is null, and B is N (not null).

So the desired output would look like this

```
N  Hierarchy                    Access
1  A                            Y
2  A >B                         N
3  A >B >C                      N
4  A >B >C >D                   N
5  A >B >C >D >E                N
6  A >B >C >D >E >F             N
7  A >B >C >D >E >F >G          Y
8  A >B >C >D >E >F >G >J       Y
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I really suggest fixing your design. Storing delimited data like this is *not* a good idea. SQL Server has a built in `hierachyid` data type, and if you don't want to use that, you are far better off using a primary and foreign key relationship.

Comment: @Larnu I am still learning TSQL. I will look into the hierarchyid. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: "Row 7's Access is null" appears to be a false statement. Perhaps you meant row 8?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm going to firstly repeat my comment:

> I really suggest fixing your design. Storing delimited data like this is *not* a good idea. SQL Server has a built in `hierachyid` data type, and if you don't want to use that, you are far better off using a primary and foreign key relationship.

This isn't pretty to achieve with your denormalised data. You have to use `LIKE` expressions and then get rid of the unwanted `JOIN`ed rows with a "TOP 1 in each group", by doing something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.DelimitedHierarchy (N int NOT NULL, 
                                     Hierarchy varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                                     Access char(1) NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DelimitedHierarchy (N, Hierarchy, Access)
VALUES (1,'A','Y'),
       (2,'A >B','N'),
       (3,'A >B >C',NULL),
       (4,'A >B >C >D',NULL),
       (5,'A >B >C >D >E',NULL),
       (6,'A >B >C >D >E >F',NULL),
       (7,'A >B >C >D >E >F >G','Y'),
       (8,'A >B >C >D >E >F >G >J',NULL);
GO

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT DH.N,
           DH.Hierarchy,
           DH.Access,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.DelimitedHierarchy DH
    WHERE DH.Hierarchy NOT LIKE '%>%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DH.N,
           DH.Hierarchy,
           ISNULL(DH.Access,r.Access),
           r.Level + 1
    FROM dbo.DelimitedHierarchy DH
         JOIN rCTE r ON DH.Hierarchy LIKE r.Hierarchy + ' >%')
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
       *
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Hierarchy ORDER BY Level DESC);
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.DelimitedHierarchy;
```

If you had a properly normalised data set, not using `hierarchyid` then the query would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.NormalisedHierarchy (N int NOT NULL, 
                                     value char(1) NOT NULL,
                                     parent char(1) NULL,
                                     Access char(1) NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.NormalisedHierarchy (N, Value, Parent, Access)
VALUES (1,'A',NULL,'Y'),
       (2,'B','A','N'),
       (3,'C','B',NULL),
       (4,'D','C',NULL),
       (5,'E','D',NULL),
       (6,'F','E',NULL),
       (7,'G','F','Y'),
       (8,'J','G',NULL);
GO

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT NH.N,
           NH.[value],
           NH.Access,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.NormalisedHierarchy NH
    WHERE NH.parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NH.N,
           NH.[value],
           ISNULL(NH.Access,r.Access),
           r.Level + 1
    FROM dbo.NormalisedHierarchy NH
         JOIN rCTE r ON NH.parent = r.[value])
SELECT *
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY [Level] ASC;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.NormalisedHierarchy;
```

Alternatively, implement a [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15). I don't include a solution for that, as I have never worked with them, and have used self referencing normalised tables.